# How to fix serana and vampires black faces in Skyrim SE?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Hi I have few mods installed but everything was fine until I started my Skyrim SE today. I realized that Serana and other vampires have black faces? Do you know what might cause this problem?

**My mod list**

```
Fores New Idles in Skyrim SE - FNIS SE [FNIS Behavior SE 7_6] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/3038/
More Enchant Ranks for Ordinator [More Enchanting Ranks] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/9275/
Reaper Paladin Armor Set [Reaper Paladin Armor Kit] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/20320/
Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch [Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266/
Enhanced Blood Textures [Enhanced Blood Textures] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2357/
Multiple Followers Framework [Multiple Followers Framework] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/24167/
Deadly Mutilation - dismemberment blood and gore [Deadly Mutilation V1_3_3 CORE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/34917
Address Library for SKSE Plugins [All in one (Special Edition)] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/32444/
UNP Female Body Renewal - A female face and body replacer [UNP Female Body Renewal 4.6] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1699/
Vampire Lord Wings Remade SSE [Vampire Lord Wings Remesh] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/55145/
GORECAP [GORECAP] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/16440/
BOSSE - Bodies of Skyrim Special Edition [BOSSE Main] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/21029/
Unread Books Glow SSE [Unread Books Glow SSE 2.2.1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1296/
Bandolier - Bags and Pouches Classic [Bandolier Bags and Pouches Classic SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2417/
Simply Bigger Vampire Lord Wings [VANILLA Bigger VL Wings - 100 percent bigger] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/19513/
Cosmetic_Vampire_Overhaul_SE-12-2
HDT-SMP (Skinned Mesh Physics) [HDT-SMP for SSE 1.5.97 v2.11] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/30872/
Vargr - The Autumn of Whiterun Patch [Vargr - The Autumn of Whiterun Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/56852/
Ordinator - Perks of Skyrim [Ordinator 9.31.0] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1137/
Standing Stones - Discover Standing Stones for perk points [Standing Stones - Discover Standing Stones for Perk Points] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/31801/
Sleep Tight SE [Sleep Tight SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/20680/
Cosmetic Vampire Overhaul - AI Overhaul and Cutting Room Floor Patches [Cosmetic Vampire Overhaul - Cutting Room Floor Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/40978
A Matter of Time - A HUD clock widget [AMatterOfTime_v3_0_0_alpha_4] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12937/
SkyUI [SkyUI_5_2_SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12604/
Spell Perk Item Distributor (SPID) [Spell Perk Item Distributor - SSE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/36869/
Deadly Spell Impacts [Deadly Spell Impacts v1_70] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12939/
Alternate Start - Live Another Life - SSE [Alternate Start - Live Another Life] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/272/
Deadly Mutilation - dismemberment blood and gore [Deadly Mutilation V1_3_3 meshes Pack CBBE ] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/34917
XP32 Maximum Skeleton Special Extended - XPMSSE [XP32 Maximum Skeleton Special Extended] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1988/
LOTR - Sword of the Witch-King SE [Witch-King's Sword] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10394/
Destructible Skyrim - Breakable Objects SE (Beta) [Destructible Skyrim - Breakable Objects (Beta)] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/28291/
Stones of Barenziah Quest Markers [BarenziahQuestMarkers SSE v1-3-1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/684
Fortified Whiterun [Fortified Whiterun] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/40094/
Fancy Bows - ENB Light Patch [Fancy Bows - ENB Light Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/61706/
Beasts of Tamriel [Beasts of Tamriel 5.2.1 Alpha] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5404/
Skyrims Unique Treasures [Skyrim Unique Treasures SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5261/
Dark Face Fix [Dark Face Head Body Colour Mismatch Bug Fix] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10522/
powerofthree's Tweaks [powerofthree's Tweaks SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/51073/
Healthy Feet Female feet - RP's Feet for Skyrim - UNPB UUNP CBBE [RP's Feet UNPB w sliders 4S] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/91261/
Serana's Hood Fix [Serana's Hood Fix] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/20243/
Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch [Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266/
Address Library for SKSE Plugins [All in one (Anniversary Edition)] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/32444/
Isilmeriel LOTR Weapons Collection SSE [Isilmeriel's LOTR Collection for SSE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/14316/
Magical College of Winterhold [Magical College of Winterhold - ESM Version] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1539/
Mystic Eyes [Mystic Eyes] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/56627/
UNP Female Body Renewal - A female face and body replacer [UNP Female Body Renewal 4.6] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1699/
True Nazgul - Armor [True Nazgul - Armor] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/43753/
Dunmeri Leaf Swords [Dunmeri Leaf Swords] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12827/
Nazgul Armor set [Nazgul Armor] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/63248/
LOTR - Sword of Strider and Companion Knife (SE) [Sword of Strider and Companion Knife] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/67837/
Forgotten Magic Redone SE [Forgotten Magic Redone SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12711/
Serana Dialogue Add-On [Serana Dialogue Add-On SE] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/32161
Destruction Magic of Cyrodiil [DestructionMagicofCyrodiil] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/9260/
Beyond Skyrim - Bruma SE [Beyond Skyrim - Bruma] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10917/
Apocalypse - Magic of Skyrim [Apocalypse 9.45.0] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1090/
Autumn in Riften [Autumn in Riften] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12159/
Beyond Skyrim - Bruma SE [Beyond Skyrim DLC Integration Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10917/
Resplendent Lich King Armor HDT [Resplendent Lichking V1.2 HDT] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/33715/
New Beginnings - Live Another Life Extension SSE [Alternate Start -- New Beginnings] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/4939/
FNIS Data (Default) [FNIS Data] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/42
Address Library for SKSE Plugins [All in one (Anniversary Edition)] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/32444/
Maximum Carnage [Maximum Carnage Animated] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/43494/
Armor Variants Expansion [Armor Variants Expansion] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/34100/
Skyrim Flora Overhaul SE [Skyrim Flora Overhaul SE (FULL) v2.72D] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2154/
LOTR-The Nazgul and the Ring of Power [The Nazgul and the Ring of Power True Nazgul Armor] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/45374/
Fores New Idles in Skyrim SE - FNIS SE [FNIS Behavior SE 7_6] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/3038/
Beyond Skyrim - Bruma SE [Beyond Skyrim - Assets] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10917/
Magical College of Winterhold [MCoW - Full AE Patch] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1539/
Marry me Serana v2-21938-2-1603153329
Highly Improved Male Body Overhaul -HIMBO- [HIMBO] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/46311/
Armor Variants Expansion - HIMBO Refit [Armor Variants Expansion - HIMBO Refit] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/67570/
Cloaks of Skyrim [Cloaks of Skyrim SSE - v1.2.1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/6369/
Dark Face Fix [Dark Face Head Body Colour Mismatch Bug Fix] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10522/
Reunited Tamriel - Morrowind 7.0 (EN) [Reunited Tamriel Morrowind Demo 7 English] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/26499/
True Storms Special Edition - Thunder Rain and Weather Redone [True Storms - Main File 1.0.2] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2472/
RaceMenu [RaceMenu Anniversary Edition v0-4-19-9] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/19080/
Vargr - A Whiterun Overhaul [Vargr - A Whiterun Overhaul - Complete 1.1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/46205/
Relationship Dialogue Overhaul - RDO SE [Relationship Dialogue Overhaul - RDO Final] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1187/
WSCO - Windsong Skyrim Character Overhaul SE [WSCO 1.1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/23504/
Kissing - Immersive Lover's Comfort [Kissing - Immersive Lovers Comfort 0_8] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/225/
Tempered Skins for Females - UNP CBBE and Vanilla [Tempered Skins for Females UNP and Vanilla] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/8505/
The Autumn of Whiterun (AOW) [The Autumn of Whiterun v1.3.1] => https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10864/
```

Comment: This one sounds suspicious: `Dark Face Fix [Dark Face Head Body Colour Mismatch Bug Fix]`, but honestly -- do you expect someone to iterate through the 50+ mods you've posted and figure out which one (or a combination, more likely) is causing this?

Comment: That being said, what troubleshooting have you attempted yourself? Is your mod load order optimized (eg. via LOOT or similar)? As Timmy Jim asked, _have_ you attempted disabling mods? Have you attempted to find the problematic mod yourself? (A binary search is generally effective -- eg. disable the first 50%; did the problem go away? now you know the problem's in the first half of them ... otherwise it's in the second half. then disable half of the ones in the problematic group; rinse and repeat until you identify the culprit.)

Comment: Hi I don't expect someone to iterate through them but I think it is caused by some of that  NPC graphic mods. Yes I tired LOOT to optimize my load order. But it seems it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I discovered that it was caused by these mods:

- WSCO - Windsong Skyrim Character Overhaul SE [WSCO 1.1]
- RaceMenu [RaceMenu Anniversary Edition v0-4-19-9]

Comment: How was it caused? What was their load order? How did you find out it was these mods that were causing the problem?

Comment: @Joachim Well I thought it was one of those NPC mods. As you can see I have had more of them and there were not compatibile with each other. I can paste there my load order if you want to to better understanding of the problem. Also I disabled that `Dark Face Fix [Dark Face Head Body Colour Mismatch Bug Fix]` as @Roddy of The frozen Peas mentoied - it seemed usless and not working. Also I am installing mods with `Vortex` and it **gaves error messages it there are missing masters in mods ,not compatibile or if they are redundant and it always offers you solution.** I also always use `LOOT`.

Comment: But you also really need to know what you're doing, which is something most users forget. With longer mod lists especially, it helps to be aware of what files are modified or overwritten. I'd still recommend Mod Organizer (but haven't used either in a while). LOOT can help, but doesn't spot all incompatibilities. Dark Face Fix was a temporary solution, for specific cases, so that doesn't say anything :)